# how to prevent procmail listening to the world

Tags: security, email, procmail

This is part of a larger effort to try and ensure my server is not infected and spamming the internet with spam emails

I had a friend take a look at the server and he said

"Your procmail is open to the world. I personally would only have
procmail listening to localhost if I was just wanting to send
mailshots from my webserver"

my assumption is that he means we can stop procmail listening to the outside world if all we are doing is using it to send mail from localhost

my question is how do I configure procmail to only listen to requests from localhost?

Comment: Are you sure your friend said `procmail` and not `postfix`? `procmail` is not a daemon so it won't ever listen to any ports nor receive data over a network connection (it's usually invoked by your MTA via a `.forward` file or similar).

Comment: While having a MTA running when you don't need one is certainly unnecessary, that is quite different from having an infected box.  If they're already on your box, they don't care what it's listening to (except maybe to harden it on your behalf so as not to have others hack it, too).

Comment: based on everything I've seen so far I think you might be right mjturner